# Web API response returns 500 from server, but I receive 'Refresh: 1' on the client

Tags: http

I'm trying to write a simple Android app for my RESTful services. For some weird reasons, I get this result in HTTP response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Pragma: no-cache
Refresh: 1; URL=http://service.aurora.phis.ir/user/word/processWordMeaningDiscoveryAnswer?wordId=9873&meaning=%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%87%DB%8C%20%D9%87%D8%A7
Connection: Close

<HTML></HTML>
```

It's very odd, because using Fiddler and re-composing the exactly same request, I get the response on another machine. I also used Wireshark on server to verify that it returns correct HTTP response.
This is the response that server returns:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 115
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://aurora.phis.ir
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 12 Jan 2017 12:59:54 GMT

............ ....... bananas ........ ........... .... ........ ............ .... ...... .......... .......... ....
```

Dots are Unicode characters, and it's OK. But I don't get the same response either in Fiddler or Android Emulator on my machine, while everything works just fine on my other machine. What is the problem?

Comment: Can you please show the piece of code that you are using in Android?

Comment: @pringi This is not an android side problem, im sure that my server returns 500 http error and on the client side in fiddler i get the 200 http response!